# JavaScript: How to read a local file (specifically a json file)?

Tags: javascript

My question is very simple:
I'd like to read a configuration json file relying on the front end side and not on the server.
The file name and path is hard-coded in the JS file.
I am not the getting its name from some file dialog like in many examples on SO.

I also tried some suggestions to use fetch like:

```
fetch('./data/properties.json')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(err => console.log(error));
```

but I always got errors like

> exh.js:30 Fetch API cannot load
> file:///C:/Users/myusername/WebAppsProjects/BBSimFE/data/properties.json.
> URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.

I also installed and CORS Chrome extension and turned it on => no help.

I also tried to understand whether I can use FileReader.
For example:

```
var fr = new FileReader();
fr.readAsText(new File([""], "./data/properties.json"));
fr.onload = function(evt){
    alert(fr.result);
 }
```

But this returns nothing.

Also, I am not using node.js so I cannot use require();

Please assist.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using import like `import data from "./data/properties.json"` and `console.log(data)`

Comment: @KaungKhantZaw Thanks. I get "Cannot use import statement outside a module" when I put the import on top of my js file. Is it the correct place?

Comment: Try adding `type = "module"` to your script tag like `<script src="src/index.js" type="module"></script>`

Comment: @KaungKhantZaw You mean to add 'type="module"' to the script tag in the html which uses the js which tryies to import the json contents?

Answer (score 1):

For security purposes, `fetch` does not work for `file` urls, so opening your file in the browser won't work. You should [set up a local testing server](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/set_up_a_local_testing_server) so XHR requests work properly. Some options include running `python -m http.server 8080` in the directory that your files are in then navigating to http://localhost:8080 in the browser, or using a plugin like [vscode's live server plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer).

Answer (score 1):

Hey) For security purposes you should not store important configuration info on your frontend side. It should be on server side.

But if you store not important info in your config file, you need to lift a server on localhost, port may be any. Also you need to do your folder with config.json is static on server side. After that you have a static folder with needed for you files, at current case it's config.json. On frontend side you need send

```
fetch('http://localhost:<your_port>/static/config.json', options);
```

if you set your static folder is static if no then replace static by your static folder name. You can check if your static file is available just go http://localhost:<your_port>/static route and you should see all files|folders inside static folder.

Comment: Thanks. Store info on the server side, even to store the sever address itself?

Comment: i'd suggest you to store server address on frontend. In your file what is responsibillity for requests to your api. It will be like const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3000'. Because when you will deploy your app on server like heroku you will not have port. All what you will have it's address like https:/ /address.

Comment: So if I understand you well, the best practice to configure server address is by setting a hard-coded value in the js file, right?